# Centering submit button

Tags: css, centering

"Send My Free Ebook" submit button at [www.Edge-Trainer.com](http://edge-trainer.com/) isn't centering when viewing in mobile.. I've tried setting width, margins to auto, text align to center, display block and many other things but I can't get it to center.

Another issue that may or many not be related is if you scroll down to the 14 Day Kick in the Butt Jumpstart Program, the gray box is outside the white box but should be centered inside. I can't figure that out either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Basically the button is not in center because of your markup. For fixing that you just put a ```padding-left: 5px;``` to your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this..

And you must you this inside your mobile size media-screen [code](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)..

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .smallcent{
        position: relative;
        right: 15px;
    }
    .btn_ebook{
        position: relative;
        right: 15px;
    }
}
```

it is 100% working...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! If I put that in my styles.css under the section @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px), it doesn't work, but if I put it directly into my index page it does work. I don't understand why. Is that where I should be putting it?

Comment: I moved my link to the styles.css to the end of my stylesheets and now it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with the size of the button. As the screen gets smaller the form does too. However the button does not have a pre-defined width, just that it is the size of the text + the padding you have given it.

There are 2 ways to go about fixing this, the first is to define an exact width, such as 75% in that case the button would get smaller and stay center aligned.

The other method is to use media queries for smaller devices and change the font size each time the screen size gets to a certain width.

Hope this helps!